# Debugging from a View file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, svn, visual-studio-debugging

Working on a C# MVC project, I can have multiple files open in Visual Studio. When I press F5 to start debugging, the debugging starts if the currently open file is:

- a controller (*.cs);
- a model (*.cs);
- a stylesheet (*.css);
- a config file (*.config);
- a partial view (*.cshtml)

However, if the open file is a View (*.cshtml), the browser opens with the "Server Error - URL not found" page.

Additional info: The solution has always been under source control with SVN but at some point, the repository location changed and from then on (I think), this strange error occurs. It didn't happen before, I could debug without thinking if a view file was open or not. The change wasn't performed by me and I lack details on it. I am not sure these things are related either.

Anyone has come across a similar issue? How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing the problem is your project setup. Do following:

> Project right click -> Properties -> Web -> Start action

Most likely it has "Current page" checked, which does not play well with ASP.NET MVC view, it just tries to open the view directly, and not via route. Every other type of file you mentioned is not detected as page, and thus VS does not try to open them as such.

You might want to choose a "Specific URL" there, or just make a habit of switching to a different file before hitting F5.

Comment: That could be it but, I checked "Specific Page" and tried many Views (Home, Main...) but I can't choose any file without getting the server error again

Comment: Again, you are choosing view as a page. This is not going to work for the same reason. Check you browser when you are trying to run the web app - url says "Views/Blah/View.cshtml", right? This is not a proper route in ASP.NET MVC, thus the Not found page. Specifc URL is your best bet here

Comment: But I don't want to specify a URL, debugs occur at localhost, from any machine. I tried leaving it black but it doesn't allow me. Nor something like "/" or "http://" - those don't work

Comment: @chiapa, well, you could try `http://localhost:<port>/`, though this is not an option if you do not have a fixed port yet. I do not have VS at hand to try now, but does "Specific Page" allow you to enter some custom url? You could just enter something like `Home/Index`

Comment: Well, I tried that and it works but I'm not sure that's an optimal solution. Anyway, my main doubt is why this started happening all of a sudden, when before I could debug from any file without problems. I think I'll create a new MVC project to see how it behaves

Comment: OK, the newly created MVC project has "Specific Page" checked with a blank input, and you can run from view, controllers, whatever. Thank you for your effort